# Salesforce for Outlook 3.4.8 returns System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error in IAddrOpenEntry: MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_ENTRYID

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-for-outlook, office-365, salesforce-outlook-sync

since a few days now, all our users reported having sync issues with the Salesforce for Outlook connector.

Until today, we used this tool as it's the only one so far able to sync contact details, including custom SF contact objects.

We use it with Office 365 clients and it used to work perfectly so far.
I've test the client on a old Windows 10, without Edge update, with told Office 2016 and the issue is the same.

I've the feeling that this ENTRYID is somehow related to the Exchange Online mailbox.
Does any of you had this issue and have found a solution?
I know SF For Outlook is planned to be stopped in 2024 but as said, we haven't found so far a valid solution to sync custom contact fields.

Ideas are welcome

D

Answer (score 0):

In case this issue occurs to others, we found out that just creating a new Contact folder in end user Mailbox and then reconfiguring the SF for Outlook connector to sync in that new folder solves the issue.